# React how too apply date filter

Tags: reactjs, filter, calendar

```
{categoryFilter.reverse().map((islem, index) => (
          <Card
            key={index}
            {...(islem.colorType
              ? { className: "cardHistoryGreen button" }
              : { className: "cardHistoryRed button " })}
          >
            <Card.Header className="cardDate">{islem.date}</Card.Header>
            <Card.Text className="cardCategory">
              {islem.IslemAciklama}
            </Card.Text>
            <Card.Text className="cardMoney">
              {islem.processType}
              {islem.moneyInput}TL
            </Card.Text>
          </Card>
```

I am already filter this cards with category. I want to add a calendar and pick start and end date and show in between this date cards.